# Populate ListView with ArrayList item on button click

Tags: android, button, android-listview

I have an arraylist `List<Cars> myCars = new ArrayList<Cars>();` My MainActivity layout has a listview and a button. There is one more layout
("each_car.xml") and its content is as below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"  >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_carName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_carMaker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My Cars class has two fields,"name" and "manufacturer".

```
public class Cars{
    String name;
    String manufacturer;
}
```

I am populating this list(myCars) through an async-task. After the task is complete i.e. inside onPostExecute(), I am calling a method in my MainActivity
which will populate a listview with the items in the list. Below is the method :-

```
public void populateListView(List<Cars> data){

    ArrayAdapter<Cars> carAdapter = new CarAdapter(MainActivity.this, data);
    ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.car_listView);
    dataList.setAdapter(carAdapter);    
}
```

Below is my CarAdapter class :-

```
public class CarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cars>{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Cars> dummyData = new ArrayList<Cars>();
    MainActivity host;

    public CarAdapter(MainActivity host, List<Cars> data)
    {
        super(host,R.layout.each_car,data);
        inflater = host.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
        dummyData = data;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        View itemView = convertView;

        if(itemView == null)
        {
            itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.each_car,parent,false);
        }

        Cars currentData = dummyData.get(position);
        Log.d("Testing Position","Position :- "+position);
        TextView carName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_carName);
        carName.setText(currentData.getName());
        TextView carMaker = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_carMaker);
        carMaker.setText(currentData.getManufacturer());
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

This is filling out the listview with the entire List (myCars) at once.

Problem :- I want to populate the listView with one item at a time when I click the button.I am not sure how should I modify my code.

Comment: show me what you have tried..!

Comment: I have updated my answer, it provides basic implementation of a list

Answer (score 0):

Check this link for custom adapter[enter link description here](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92). Once the list is populated pass the list into constructor of adapter and don't forget to call notifydatasetchanged. It will update the listview whenever an new item is added or removed from a listview.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of tutorials. You need to do some research and follow tutorials if you do not know what to do. [link one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html), [link two](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html) and [link three](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/)

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

adapter class

```
    public class myListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    List<String> item_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public myListAdapter(){

    }

    void add(String item_text){
        item_list.add(item_text);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return item_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        TextView tvText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_text);
        tvText.setText(item_list.get(position));
        return null;
    }

}
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Implementation in onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    myListAdapter adapter = new myListAdapter();

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter.add("Some value");

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: Posts links as comments. or elaborate your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
This may help you ...   
public class car extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Cars> {
     @Override
      protected ArrayList<Cars> doInBackground(Void... params) {
         ... add your list here...
         return myCars ;
     }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Cars> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
        //as per your requirement  
    adapter_car = new SimpleAdapter(ExchangeRateActivity.this, result,
                R.layout.row, from, to);
   list_view.setAdapter(adapter_car);

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample and easy way first you want to give the elements of 0 index element then on the next click you first clear the listview and then call your Adapter class with 2 element and repeat the same thing with some counter that takes the number of click and call you Adapter class with the limit of that Array list May be this Strategy help you..